# "Undefined is not a function error" on $.tagHandler()

Tags: jquery, tag-handler

I am working in ASP.NET MVC4. When jQuery is loaded, I got an error: `Undefined is not a function`:

[image]

In HTML version, it's working correctly, but when it loaded through compiler it is not working correctly.

Comment: I think there is no element with id main_recipients so the identifier is undefined

Comment: thanks. sorry everything is exist i mean id is also there

Comment: `$.fn.tagHandler` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Tag Handler plugin](https://github.com/ioncache/Tag-Handler) for jQuery, then this error message might indicate that the Tag-Handler plugin isn't loading correctly.

You can use your browser's developer tools to figure out if the script is being loaded or not (for instance, in Chrome, check to see if the appropriate script is being loaded under the Network tab).